# How to manage links in a Nextjs application

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I have a Nextjs application. The app will grow to a nice size (200 pages)

What is the best way to manage links. Some pages will have navigation buttons and and hrefs, hyperlinks.

I am looking for solution to manage

Example: pages -> about, contact, support, home, blog. But when you have 200 pages and you are hardcoding `<a href="/about"> </a>`  if I delete or change the about page name I have to go in all 200 pages and update this

Answer (score 0):

Navigate with click :

```js
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
//...
const router = useRouter()
<button
onClick={() => {
router.push('/url')
}}
>Navigate</button>
```

Navigate with Link :

```js
import Link from 'next/link';
//...
<Link href="/url">Navigate</Link>
```

And if you have 200 url you should make 200 links you cannot optimize that, but you can create a file for all your link then import it everywhere and when you have to update one `path` you do it inside this file :

```
import Link from "next/link";
export const HomeLink = () => {
  return <Link href="/">Navigate To Home</Link>;
};
export const SettingsLink= () => {
  return <Link href="/settings">Navigate To Settings</Link>;
};
//...
```

and from the file in which you want to navigate :

```
import { HomeLink, SettingsLink } from "../your_path";
//...
<HomeLink />
<SettingsLink/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I create a routes file with all my hard-coded routes and use the `const` throughout my app. I use [trailing slash](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/trailing-slash), so they need to be appended to all routes.

This setup works well for me, and I've used it on numerous projects with hundreds of routes. It saved a lot of time over the years when inevitably, I needed to change a route's `href` or name.

---

My routes file is similar to this:

```js
export const ROUTE_HOME = {
  href: "/",
  name: "Home",
};
export const ROUTE_ABOUT = {
  href: "/about/",
  name: "About",
};
```

I use them like

```js
import Link from 'next/link';
import {ROUTE_HOME, ROUTE_ABOUT} from 'your/path/to/routes';

<Link href={ROUTE_HOME}>{ROUTE_HOME.name}</Link>
<Link href={ROUTE_ABOUT}>{ROUTE_ABOUT.name}</Link>
```

On larger projects, I break the routes out into separate files.

```js
src > const > routes.ts // top-level routes
src > modules > auth > const > routes.ts // only auth routes
```